# Keep form ID's output value on page after reload using .innerHTML

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a search form where onclick of the submit button it displays the form value underneath. This is the code:

```html
 <input type="text" name="searchfield" id="searchfield" value="" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" id="submitSearch" value="Submit" onclick="document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = document.getElementById('searchfield').value" />
<div id="output"></div>
```

It works fine, but once submitted (the page reloads rather than going to another page) the value in the output div disappears.

Is there a way to make the value remain, even after page reload?

I'm trying to find the simplest way to achieve this.

Comment: Several ways; store it in a session, add it in your link or just submit your form with jquery/ajax.

Comment: One way to keep them is to pass those values as the page reload and take them from the URL or use php to place them back into the page.... Unless you use `AJAX` to post that data, `ajax` will run in the background keeping the client on the page while that data is being posted meaning no page refresh is needed or you can use cookies/local storage.

Comment: Yes, you can use get values (most used for a search fields like Google does https://www.google.com/search?q=value), sessions, ajax or even cookie/localstorege (better don't).

Comment: Store it in local storage. And check for whether the output is set or not. If it is set then simply just put the local storage data inside output div otherwise don't. It is not suggested if the Output div content is very large.

Comment: Sessions sounds like a good solution.. I've googled how to do this but I can't seems to tie it in with the form value. I started page with `<?php session_start(); ?>` and then added `<?php print_r($_SESSION); ?>` with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in severals ways for example using get values, sessions, cookies, localstorage, ajax,...

Since you are trying to build a search form GET values seems the most appropriate (or ajax too).

An example of code:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="get">
  <input type="text" name="searchfield" id="searchfield" value="" />
  <input type="submit" id="submitSearch" value="Submit"/>
</form>

<div id="output">

<?php

if(isset($_GET['searchfield'])) {
  echo $_GET["searchfield"];
 }

?>

</div>
```

Check AJAX if you don't want a reload.